# Python 3 returning dictionary from a function case

Tags: python, function

I have python function that should return diction:

```
def load_cred(FILE):
    key_for_enc = getpass(prompt='Key for encrypted credentials file: ', stream=None)
    cipher = AESCipher(key_for_enc)
    crd_dict={}
    with open(FILE, 'r') as fh:
        for line in fh:
            dec_line = cipher.decrypt(line)
            # print("line: {}".format(dec_line))
            dec_line.strip()
            start_string, user, password =  dec_line.split(10*'|')
            crd_dict[start_string] = (user, password)
            #print("1: {} 2: {} 3: {}".format(start_string,user,password))
    print("crd diction: {}".format(crd_dict))        
    return crd_dict
```

but when I call it from other script like that:

```
        Data_cred = load_cred(CRED_FILE)
        print ("Data type: {}".format(type(Data_cred)))
        print("Data: ".format(Data_cred))
```

The returned dictionary don't appear as a returned value... Could anybody help me with this? Notice that within the function load_cred , crd_dict have it's items.. but outside it doesn't. I still don't get it why..

```
Key for encrypted credentials file:
crd diction: {'first_line': ('User1', 'Pass1')}
Data type: <class 'dict'>
Data len:
Data:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `load_cred()` is returning the dictionary. You just forgot to add the *replacement field* in the last line when printing it. -

```
print("Data: {}".format(Data_cred))
```